# Roll back git master repository and branch commits from rollback point

Tags: linux, ubuntu, git, ubuntu-11.04, github

I have a Git repository set up. This repository has almost 700 commits, but all of them is in the `master` branch. I would like to take an approach in which I roll back this `master` branch (this rollback involves roughly 50 commits) to an earlier point to make it stay there **and** starting from that point, branch out all later commits into a separate branch.

#### Graphical explanation

Current state:

```
|-.---.---.---.---.---.---.---.---+ master
 aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh  HEAD
```

Desired state:

```
|-.---.---.--\-|  master
 aaa bbb ccc  \
               \
                \.---.---.---.---.---+ seperate-branch
                ddd eee fff ggg hhh  HEAD
```

So that the `master` branch is rolled back to the `ccc` commit and every commit from that point (`ddd` and onwards) are moved into a `seperate-branch`.

I am fairly new to Git but have got myself to the journeyman levels, still this advanced usage is pretty above my head. I am using Ubuntu 11.04 as my system. The repository (apart from being stored locally) is having a `remote` set up to GitHub (if this is to make any difference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know the commit you want to rollback to, I'm calling it `SHA1`

```
git checkout -b seperate-branch
git checkout master
git reset SHA1 --hard
```

And you're done.

To push it on GitHub, you will need to do

```
git push --force origin master
```